# Is there a join that returns a table where one row has been merged?

Tags: mysql, join

I have  a table called `phone`, that has 1 column called `names` and another called `number`. I have a second table called `address`, that has 1 column called `family` and another called `address`. `family` and `names` have the same values however `family` has some repeats. I would like to join these into a table that has `family` and `names` as 1 column and then the `phone` and `address` as another. However, because of the size mismatch (more addresses than phone numbers) I am not sure if this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like `SELECT * from phone JOIN address ON phone.names=address.names GROUP BY family;`?

Comment: that seemed to be close, except it removed the address entries that used the same names

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
Table 1
Name number
Bob  1234
Tom  3456

Table 2
family address
Bob    MD
Bob    NJ
Bob    NY
Tom    NC

Result
Name  Number  Address
Bob   1234    MD/NJ/NY
```

Comment: actually was going for having the address column stay the same and the numbers just be repeated for each matching family

Answer (score 0):

Assuming " was going for having the address column stay the same and the numbers just be repeated for each matching family" as in one of the comments:

```
 select 
    A.family, A.address, P.number 
from 
    address A
    left join phone P on A.family = P.Name
order by 
    A.family, A.address, P.number
```

### [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11df5/2)

FTR, if it were me i would probably be more interested in this instead:

```
select 
    A.family, 
    group_concat(distinct A.address separator '\n') Address, 
    group_concat(distinct P.number separator ',') Phone
from 
    address A
    left join phone P on A.family = P.Name
group by family
order by 
    A.family, A.address desc, P.number
```